# Email fields are not auto-populating metadata

Tags: harmon.ie

We have Enterprise version Harmon.ie, I have verified the Email Header Mapping is correct, and have completed the configuration of content types for metadata successfully.

When we upload an email from Outlook through harmon.ie to the library in SharePoint, it does not auto-populate any metadata. If we upload the email a 2nd time and choose to update the existing document with a new version, the metadata will populate most of the time with some exceptions.

We have not been able to track down any reason for this auto-update of metadata to be failing, and cannot find troubleshooting tips for this issue in these forums or on the Harmon.ie site.

Let me know if you need additional information, or any troubleshooting steps you can recommend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Support for harmon.ie enterprise customers provided directly via support@harmon.ie or https://harmonie.zendesk.com.